# ¿Como crear un sub reporte en iReport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

He creado un reporte en iReport, que a su vez tiene un sub reporte. El problema 
es que imprime el sub reporte varias veces.

```
    Titulo 1 Titulo 2 Titulo 3 Titulo 4
    valor 1 valor 2 valor 3 valor 4 
    valor 1 valor 2 valor 3 valor 4 
    valor 1 valor 2 valor 3 valor 4 
    valor 1 valor 2 valor 3 valor 4 
ESTO SON TODOS LOS REGISTROS DEL SUB-REPORTE

    valor 1 valor 2 valor 3 valor 4 
    valor 1 valor 2 valor 3 valor 4 
    valor 1 valor 2 valor 3 valor 4 
    valor 1 valor 2 valor 3 valor 4 
ESTO SON TODOS LOS REGISTROS DEL SUB-REPORTE

    valor 1 valor 2 valor 3 valor 4 
    valor 1 valor 2 valor 3 valor 4 
    valor 1 valor 2 valor 3 valor 4 
    valor 1 valor 2 valor 3 valor 4 
ESTO SON TODOS LOS REGISTROS DEL SUB-REPORTE
```

¿Como puedo hacer que solo se imprima una vez, el sub reporte?

He agregado una nueva banda `detail` pero hace lo mismo. Si lo agrego en la banda de `sumary` sólo imprime pero al tamaño que se le dio,
no aumenta dinámicamente el tamaño como en la banda detail.

¿Se puede hacer que crezca dinámicamente? ¿o qué solución le puedo dar?

Answer (score 1):

Para el dinamismo del tamaño únicamente se puede estando en el detalle, proba enviando una lista o datasource desde java, a mi me funcionó (no sabría el resultado si es consulta directa sql)!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La banda detail se repite con cada entrada del datasource. Deberás incluir el subReport en una de las bandas que no se repiten, cabecera/pie de pagina o tabla.

Comment: He incluido el subReport en otra de las bandas que no se repiten, pero el problema es que si el subReport tiene muchos datos, la seccion no crece conforme la cantidad de registros, si no que se queda con el tamaño predefinido

Comment: Eso puede deberse a alguna configuración de las bandas.

Comment: ¿Has probado a ejectuar el subreport por separado para ver si se te corta o te lo imprime completo?

Answer (score -1):

Cuando tienes un reporte principal y varios sub-reportes como muestro a continuación
tienes que asegurarte que en la consulta que haces en tu reporte principal no tenga mas de un resultado ya que por cada resultado se te repetirá una ves cada sub reporte.

la mayoría de las consultas o sub-reportes tienes varios datos y cuando las pones en las bandas que no crecen como el footer se desbordan y te dan error.

si los sub-reportes aparecen uno sobre otro hay que crear una nueva banda detail y poner allí el segundo sub-reporte, después cambiar la propiedad de la banda Type Split creo que es por Strecht

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]